# Почему разное отображение сайта при загрузке с текстового редактора и FTP-сервера?

Tags: css, веб-программирование, ftp

И так, так выглядит сайт, когда я его запустил с редактора:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А так, когда отображается на FTP :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему съезжают стили?
Файлы одинаковые, все идентично, а на FTP они начинают сжиматься, лезть друг на друга
Спасибо за помощь

Comment: Что значит с редактора и что значит с FTP? И как по мне - так картинки идентичны.

Comment: Тоже пытался найти 10 отличий. Нашел. Наверняка, проблема с путями к стилям, шрифтам. Смотрите в консоли браузера 404 ошибки.

Comment: Ну, запускаю с WebStorm'a на локальном хосте-1я картинка. А 2я - на FTP сервере
Не знаю, нет там ошибок
Пути указаны верно